# Is my betta fish aging or is he sick?

Tags: fish, betta, senior-pet

My betta fish, named Lushi, has been progressively getting worse for the past few months. I bought him in September, 2019 (9 months ago) from Petco -- although he seemed fully grown when I bought him, I couldn't tell you his exact age. He's had what looks like worsening fin rot for the past few months. He lives in a fully decorated (only silk plants with tons of hiding spots) 10 gallon aquarium alone. He receives regular water changes of 25-50% either weekly or biweekly. He is fed the right amount (never been bloated) with an occasional fast day. I test his water every water change and all numbers come back with flying colors. I started noticing his fin loss about 2-3 months ago.

I contacted a veterinarian and they suggested a hospital tank to treat him with 'Bettafix' -- I did what they advised, yet his fins never grew back to normal. After that failed attempt, I read many great reviews on aquarium salt - I've been properly (following directions of quantity as well as dissolving it prior to adding it to the tank) administering it every water change.

Over the past month I have been noticing his lack of interest in me. He used to greet me every time I came to his tank, now he just hides and sleeps most of the day. He used to swim around the tank energetically, now he just swims when it's to get food and floats around the rest of the time. I also never see him flare anymore (he used to flare all the time in certain circumstances).

His coloring is fading -- he used to be a beautiful metallic blue marble with white patches, now he is turning mostly white starting from his body. I want to know if I'm the one that's causing this or if he could just be getting old. I often doubt that it's the latter because I can't imagine him to be over the age of 2. I love this little guy to pieces and just want to make his life comfortable and happy.

Please tell me if there is something I should (or shouldn't) be doing.